# What is wrong with my code on calculating area of square/rectangle?

Tags: python

```
shape = input("Square or Rectangle ? : ")

width = float(input("Enter The Width : "))

if input in shape :

 "Square, square"

 area = width * width

 print ("")

 print ("The Area Of The Given Square is" + area)








length = float(input("Enter The Area : "))

area = width * length

print ("")

print ("The Area Of The given Rectangle is ", area)

input("Enter To Exit")
```

I am new to Python scripting and wanted to make a simple py that calculates the area of a square or rectangle. But when I open it, it asks for the "Square or Rectangle ?" I input Square, then it asks for width and it abruptly closes. Same happens when I put in Rectangle. Again I am a noobie at python and just going off of what I can find. I am not sure on how to frame a question for this to search and find an answer so I resorted to making one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

1) The condition

```
if input in shape:
```

You never defined a variable "input". Furthermore, I'm not real sure why you are checking a condition here anyways. If you're trying to verify that shape is either a rectangle or square consider this code instead:

```
if shape in ["rectangle", "square"]:
```

2) The code

```
"Square, square"
```

does nothing, and is in fact invalid syntax.

3) The line

print("The area of the given square is" + area)

is invalid string concatenation for the print function. (note you can concatenate this way OUTSIDE of the print function)
Use commas instead.

```
print("The area of the given square is", area)
```

Comment: Can you make a full code for me so I can understand better?

Comment: `"Square, square"` is useless here, but the syntax is perfectly valid. Such unused strings are even very common: all the docstrings are built this way.

Comment: Also, using '+' between a string and a number is always invalid, wherever you try to use it.

Comment: 'The code `"Square", "square"` is invalid' => plain wrong, it is perfectly valid, it's a tuple of two strings. It's useless but that doesn't make it "invalid". '

Comment: 'The line `print("The area of the given square is" + area)` is invalid string concatenation for the print function. (note you can concatenate this way OUTSIDE of the print function)' => complete nonsense.  The fact that the expression is used as argument to a function or not doesn't change anything here. The expression will raise a TypeError because `area` is a float, but this has __nothing__ to do with `print()`.

Comment: 'Use commas instead' => Nope, learn to use string formatting instead.

Answer (score 0):

This can work:

```
shape = raw_input("Square or Rectangle : ")

if shape == 'Square':
    width = float(raw_input("Enter The Width : "))
    area = width * width
    print ("")
    print ("The Area Of The Given Square is " + str(area))

if shape == 'Rectangle':
    width = float(raw_input("Enter The Width : "))
    length = float(raw_input("Enter The length : "))
    area = width * length
    print ("")
    print ("The Area Of The given Rectangle is " + str(area))
```

Rest you can improve accordingly.

Comment: This just closes it instantly as I open it doesnt ask me for anything. I tried putting input at the end of it to no avail

Comment: What platform are you coding on? And python version?